# CDB crashes in Qt

Tags: qt, debugging, windbg

I have a Qt 5.4 project on Windows 7 using MSVC 2013 and the CDB debugger. 
When I attempt to debug the program, the debug log shows that the debugger crashes. I can run the program without debugging.

The relevant error message is

> Cannot execute '"C:...\Qt\build-GENOVA->Clone_of_Desktop_Qt_5_4_0_MSVC2013_64bit-Debug\debug\GENOVA.exe"', Win32 error >     0n50
>       "The request is not supported."
>   Debuggee initialization failed, Win32 error 0n50
>       "The request is not supported."

What's going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to `Qtcreator->option->build&run->debuggers` to see the version of your cdb.

It may because you are using a 32bit cdbto debug a 64bit program. if it is 32bit, Try to uninstall it and install 64bit one.

If your cdb is 64bit, try to use windbg.exe(at the same folder of cdb.exe) to open your executable file to see more error details.

Comment: The CDB is 64 bit.
Windbg throws an error that Qt5Widgets.dll is not installed, which is not true. I've never used windbg.exe before. How do I fix that?

Comment: @BenK Did you add qt path to your PATH before?

Comment: no, but the IDE is supposed to take care of the PATHs

Comment: This may be the source of the problem:
In the debugger log, it says I am using a 64 bit ABI as intended:
`ABI: x86-windows-msvc2013-pe-64bit`
But later there's this:
` C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\cdb.exe`
`using C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\lib\qtcreatorcdbext32\qtcreatorcdbext.dll`

So it looks like a 32 bit CDB version is being used with the corresponding 32 bit .dll in Qt Creator, but the ABI is 64 bit. I'm going to try to fix this.

Comment: I know I said before that the CDB was 64 bit, but it wasn't. I THOUGHT it was and didn't check carefully enough. What happened here is that Qt used the auto-detected 32 bit version of CDB. Argh. So I had to go to the kit settings and tell it to use the other one. It works now and Qt Creator correctly uses its 64 bit version of qtcreatorcdbext.dll.