# Qt Creator can't start cdb debugger

Tags: c++, qt

Has anyone ever figured out that magic combination of versions of qmake, cdb, Qt Creator and Visual Studio which will allow to start cdb.exe. It always gives "The CDB process terminated". Below is the information about tools.

[image: Qt Creator]

[image: Qt Kit 5.15.0]

[image: Qt Creator detected debuggers]

[image: Debugger versions]

Comment: Not a magic combination for sure. Always works for me. That is something else. Maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28552694/cdb-crashes-in-qt

Comment: In the Debugger log I can see that it tries to load 64bit library  C:\QtOnline\Tools\QtCreator\lib\qtcreatorcdbext64\qtcreatorcdbext.dll.